# How to rebase a svn fetched branch onto the master on Git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, rebase, branching-and-merging

I created a git repository from an existing SVN repo. In the SVN structure, I have the trunk and one branch (say, branch_01). The trunk is at the Revision 8, and the branch code, despite the changes, is updated until revision 4.

After I fetched the SVN repo into a git one, I ended up with the following structure in my git repo:

```
trunk      A(4)------B(6)---------C(8)

branch_01       D(5)--------E(7)---------F(9)
```

My question is, how to I rebase branch_01 for the git repo structure be like this?

```
trunk      A(4)------B(6)---------C(8)
              \
branch_01       D(5)--------E(7)---------F(9)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you use git-svn, better never touch commits with git-svn-id signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your diagram above, where A(4) is 2 commits before the current trunk C(8):

```
git rebase --onto trunk~2 branch_01
```

If the diagram provided is simplified, it would probably be easier to find the explicit hash for the revision 4 commit, and then use that in place of `trunk~2` in the command above.

**Note Dmitry's warning**: only do this if you are abandoning the SVN repository. If you intend to continue using git-svn, you don't want to do this.